# Copying MySQL Database to another machine

Tags: mysql, copy

I have a MySQL Database on mt Windows computer. I need to take one database and copy it to another machine. The other machine also runs windows and has MySQL Database. 
The two machines cannot be connected through internet. 
What shall I do? How can that be done through USB-card?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a export DB Mysqldump in a sql  file and copy the sql file to `USB card` and `import` it into the other machine.Follow the steps it would help you to achieve it

To make `mysql dump`  for reference [see here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)
Sample:

```
mysqldump -u admin -p passwd DB_Name > file/path/filename.sql
```

`import` the `sql` file to the `mysql DB`  as

sample :

```
  mysql > use DB_Name;
  mysql >source yourfile.sql
```

(or)

```
  mysql -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD DATABASE-NAME < file/path/filename.sql
```

Correct me if 'm wrong

Answer (score 2):

The best way it dump your DB as SQL file. And then import on another machine.

```
mysqldump -uuser -i uutfile.sql -p db_name 
mysql -uuser -p < uutfile.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the backup (sql dump) of the current database, and execute the backup in the other machine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Export the data with:

   mysqldump db_name > backup-file.sql
2. Use the stick
3. Import the data with:

   mysql -u username -p database < backup-file.sql

Answer (score 1):

The [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) package has a backup and restore procedure built in to it. The database backup is really just a long SQL file that can be re-played into another database in order to replicate your original data. It can even schedule backups.

There is also the command-line tool `mysqldump` that does the same thing but is not as easy to use. If you're doing this frequently you'll want to script it so you don't need to remember the specific command-line options:

```
 mysqldump --single-transaction --quick --user=... --password=... database | gzip -9 > backup.sql.gz
 gunzip -dc backup.sql.gz | mysql --user=... --password=...
```

Comment: Does windows support gzip compression?

Comment: If you have `gzip` installed, yes. Otherwise I'd use the Workbench tool.