# Copy mysql database from one machine to another

Tags: mysql, netbeans

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copying MySQL Database to another machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916959/copying-mysql-database-to-another-machine)

I am doing a java project and want to copy my database from one machine to another but when i copy the folder having the .opt and .frm files only the table names are copied.Neither the data nor the columns are copied. Please help me out.The mysql dump command also does not work when i execute it in netbeans.

Comment: Follow this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916959/copying-mysql-database-to-another-machine/12917170#12917170) it could be handy support you to solve

Comment: Dup @Thanga http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916959/copying-mysql-database-to-another-machine

Comment: @Thanga i am trying to execute the following command in my netbeans mysql space but it generates an error.
  mysqldump -u root -p  ussereg > c:/abc.sql

Comment: @HarshitSharaff try to run dump on console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-migration.html) for instructions how to do that.

Those are not the only files that you should copy. You should also copy `ibdata` files, this is where your InnoDB data actually is (actually, check your my.ini to see where your data files are). Also, MyISAM databases are different...to copy MyISAM database, it is sufficient just to copy folder for that database (it contains .myd and .myi files, which are data and index file, respectivly).

In the given link you should find all neccessary instructions, as well as some other ways to do that migration.

Comment: would ibdata files give path problems on a different machine.

Comment: If you are moving the whole server there, then no...just copy files (if you are running the same mysql version). If you want to move just some MyISAM databases, again no problem, just copy database folder into data folder on the destination server. If you want to move ibdata files and there are already ibdata files on the destination server that you don't want to override, then there is a problem and you should use some other way to move only that particular InnoDB database (mysqldump might be the best).

Comment: thanks for your help man.The database works fine on my other system.